# Add multiple columns using alter command in Exasol DB

Tags: exasolution, exasol

Is it possible to add multiple columns to a table in a single query execution, using alter table in exasol?

example:

`Alter table Employee add column phone_number varchar(256), add column address varchar(256)`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in one command in Exasol, but in Exasol DDL commands do not auto-commit, so you can put them in the same transaction. You could do:

```
 set autocommit off;
 alter table t1 add column c1 varchar(100);
 alter table t1 add column c2 varchar(100);
 alter table t1 add column c3 varchar(100);
 commit;
 set autocommit on;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. According to the documentation it is impossible.